# How to autofill Edit form with old Information of a user?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.1, laravel-5.3

i have this form "Modifier Technicien" with which I will modify the information of a technician, the modifications will affect two tables of my database table user and table technician. I want my form to be autofilled with the information of the technician I chose to modify. Thank you

[image]

**edit.blade.php**

```
@extends('Layouts/app')
@extends('Layouts.master')
@section('content')
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-10">
            <h1>Modifier Technicien</h1>
        <form action="{{ route('technicien.update', $moyenne_avis->id , $actif->id  ) }}" method="post">
        {{csrf_field()}}
        {{ method_field('PATCH') }}



          <div class="form-group">
                <label for="">Nom</label>
                <input id="nom" type="text" class="form-control" name="nom" value="{{ old('nom') }}" required autofocus>

                            @if ($errors->has('nom'))
                                <span class="help-block">
                                    <strong>{{ $errors->first('nom') }}</strong>
                                </span>
                            @endif
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="">Prenom</label>
                <input id="prenom" type="text" class="form-control" name="prenom" value="{{ old('prenom') }}" required autofocus>

                            @if ($errors->has('prenom'))
                                <span class="help-block">
                                    <strong>{{ $errors->first('prenom') }}</strong>
                                </span>
                            @endif
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="">Telephone</label>
                <input id="tel" type="text" class="form-control" name="tel" value="{{ old('tel') }}" required autofocus>

                            @if ($errors->has('tel'))
                                <span class="help-block">
                                    <strong>{{ $errors->first('tel') }}</strong>
                                </span>
                            @endif
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="">Mobile</label>
                <input id="mobil" type="text" class="form-control" name="mobil" value="{{ old('mobil') }}" required autofocus>

                            @if ($errors->has('mobile'))
                                <span class="help-block">
                                    <strong>{{ $errors->first('mobil') }}</strong>
                                </span>
                            @endif
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="">Role</label>
                <input id="role" type="text" class="form-control" name="role" value="{{ old('role') }}" required autofocus>

                            @if ($errors->has('role'))
                                <span class="help-block">
                                    <strong>{{ $errors->first('role') }}</strong>
                                </span>
                            @endif
            </div>



            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="">Moyenne Avis</label>
                <input type="text"  name ="moyenne_avis" class="form-control"value="{{old('moyenne_avis')}}">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <div class="form-group">
                <label for="">Etat</label>
                <input type="text"  name ="actif" class="form-control"value="{{old('actif')}}">
            </div>




            <div class="form-group">

                <input type="submit" value = "enregistrer" class="form-control btn btn-primary">
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
@endsection
```

**controller**

```
public function edit($id)
{
    $technicien=technicien::find($id);
    $users = user::orderBy('id', 'asc')->get();
    return view('technicien.edit',['moyenne_avis'=>$technicien],['actif'=>$technicien],['user_id'=>$technicien])->with('user', $users);
}

/**
 * Update the specified resource in storage.
 *
 * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
 * @param  int  $id
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
 */
public function update(Request $request, $id)
{
     technicien::where('id', $id)->update($request->all());
     return redirect('technicien/edit');
}
```

**route.php**

```
Route::get('/technicien/{id}/edit', 'TechnicienController@edit');
Route::put('/technicien/{id}', 'TechnicienController@update')-
>name('technicien.update');
```

Answer (score 2):

```
/**
 * Retrieve an old input item.
 *
 * @param  string  $key
 * @param  mixed   $default
 * @return mixed
 */
 function old($key = null, $default = null)
 {
     return app('request')->old($key, $default);
 }
```

`old()` function has 2 params. First one is from session, second one is default.

So you can use like:

```
<input id="nom" type="text" class="form-control" name="nom" value="{{ old('nom', $actif->nom) }}" required autofocus>
```

Comment: Your view syntax is wrong! `function view($view = null, $data = [], $mergeData = []) {}` ! Use only one array for data