# How to autofill Edit form with old Information from two different tables?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.1, laravel-5.3

I have this form "Edit tache". Editing one "tache" affects two tables user and technicien, when i choose to edit tache the edit form is autofilled with information from the technicien table but the fields related to the table user are not autofilled. How could i autofill the form with information from the two tables? Thank you.

[image]

**controller**

```
public function edit($id)
{
    $technicien=technicien::find($id);
    $user = user::orderBy('id', 'asc')->get();
    return view('technicien.edit',['moyenne_avis'=>$technicien],['actif'=>$technicien],['user_id'=>$technicien])->with('users', $user );
}

public function update(Request $request, $id)
{
    // do some request validation
    $technicien=technicien::find($id);
    $technicien->update($request->all());
    return redirect('technicien');
}
```

**View**

```
@extends('Layouts/app')
@extends('Layouts.master')
@section('content')
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-10">
            <h1>Modifier Tache</h1>
        <form action="{{ route('technicien.update', $actif->id , $moyenne_avis->id ) }}" method="post">
        {{csrf_field()}}
        {{ method_field('PATCH') }}


            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="">Nom</label>
                <input id="nom" type="text" class="form-control" name="nom" value="{{ old('nom') ? old('nom') : $actif->nom }}" required autofocus>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="">Prenom</label>
                <input id="nom" type="text" class="form-control" name="nom" value="{{ old('nom') ? old('nom') : $actif->nom }}" required autofocus>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="">moyenne Avis</label>
                <input type="text"  name ="moyenne_avis" class="form-control"value ="{{$moyenne_avis->moyenne_avis}}" >
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="">Etat Technicien</label>
                <input type="text"  name ="actif" class="form-control"value ="{{$actif->actif}}" >
            </div>



            <div class="form-group">

                <input type="submit" value = "enregistrer" class="form-control btn btn-primary">
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
@endsection
```

**route**

```
Route::get('/technicien/{id}/edit', 'TechnicienController@edit');
Route::put('/technicien/{id}', 'TechnicienController@update')-
>name('technicien.update');
```

Comment: why do you have two inputs with the same name?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to autofill Edit form with old Information of a user?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49026516/how-to-autofill-edit-form-with-old-information-of-a-user)

Comment: Please do not post a new version of the same question, instead [edit] your existing question!

Answer (score 0):

```
$user = user::find($id);
```

if they are retrieved using one id on the controller, else please tell the relation between them.

and in your view, i don't see a reason to check old since its not updated yet! use

```
{{$user->nom)}}
```

Comment: Thank you but nothing changed trying this